# monitor running services and ports

Tags: monitoring, systemd, munin

What is the best way to monitor running services and ports on a system with `systemd`?

My intent is to alert me, when a service stops running or if a new service is listening on a new port (possibly a security breach).

Currently, I have a script that uses `netstat` to see the open ports and compares it with what is expected.

- Is there some sort of utility I should be using?
- Also, can `systemd` alert me or again, should I just my my script
  that will be executed via cron?

I have `munin` installed and it does monitor things, but as for alerts, I don't see it having the capability as I describe.

Comment: maybe xymon does what you want? http://xymon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: xymon looks like it would be more of a ping/request type tool whereas I am looking at what ports are open listening.  I think netstat would still be the way to go as it does just that.